# process running batch which dont do what inside it

Tags: c#, process, batch-processing

I have searched a lot of ways to run a batch file with process in c#, all of them didn't help me.

the actions of the batch file are: using psexec, it connects to remote control and stops there some services. after that it deletes a lot of files and then copies the new ones, connecting again ,using psexec to the computer and starts services.

All those action take awhile when I execute the batch by myself. But when I execute the batch file using process it finish in 5 seconds and show all the output it should.
I found out that it haven't done anything. Just show up the output it should do when it successfully do it.

I am using this code to execute the batch

```
batch = new Process();
batch.StartInfo.FileName = batchPath;
batch.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
batch.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
batch.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
batch.OutputDataReceived +=  new DataReceivedEventHandler(IncomingOutput);
batch.Start();
batch.BeginOutputReadLine();
batch.WaitForExit(TimeWait * 1000);
batch.CancelOutputRead();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of batchPath exactly?

Comment: this is the value : Application.StartupPath + @"\" + SelectedNames[i]

Comment: What I was hoping to determine is if it were equal to "c:\some\path\psexec.exe" or "c:\some\path\psexec.exe -with -all -your -commandline -args -too"